# How open link with hash (#) in new window with electron?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want open link in new window. Link with hash (#). After hash going page for my JS framework.
I do:

```
const modalPath = path.join('file://', __dirname, 'index.html#','message',chat_id,'child-window');
let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 400, height: 200, show: false, frame: false});
win.loadURL(modalPath);
win.show();
```

It is worked for mac, but not work for Windows (open only index.html- mainpage)

Answer (score -1):

Using `path.join` to build a URL is not a good idea since the path separators will differ between platforms, on Windows you'll end up with something like `file://\dirname\index.html#\message\chat_id\child-window`, whereas on Mac/Linux you'll get `file://dirname/index.html#/message/chat_id/child-window`. What you should do instead is something like:

```
url.format({
  protocol: 'file',
  pathname: `${__dirname}/index.html#/message/${chat_id}/child-window`
})`
```